# JPA sequences using autogeneration

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I have created for an Entity an auto generated id like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```

and when tried to persist the entity I got the error:

> > Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view
> >     does not exist
>
> Error Code: 942 Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ?
>   WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?    bind => [2 parameters bound] Query:
>   DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT =
>   SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)

I have created an sequence table in my Oracle schema called SEQUENCE ;-) and after that I'm getting this error:

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02201: sequence not allowed here
>   Error Code: 2201
>   Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
>       bind => [2 parameters bound]
>   Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")

What can be done in order to persist the entity into the database using Eclipslink? :-)

Sincerely

Comment: Can you provide the code, you used to create the sequence table in your Oracle schema called SEQUENCE.

Comment: Thank u Jayashree, I have found the problem. The issue was caused by missing rights to create and drop table on connect  schema used to connect to database.

Comment: "AUTO" strategy means the JPA provider can use whichever strategy it wants. Use "TABLE" and EclipseLink should create a separate table defined by `@TableGenerator`

Comment: If you are targeting Oracle you will probably get better performance with sequences than with tables, i.e. GenerationType.SEQUENCE. If you don't have a compelling reason to use AUTO you may want to check that out.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep I will change the generation type.

Comment: That doesn’t seem true. Why would you get better performance with a sequence over a table? If both are configured optimally for the application, both should give comparable performance. I wouldn’t switch to using one over the other until you know what those optimal settings really are or you could be making things worse